# How can this be the output?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

It is simple program, but the output of the program is so unexpected .

Programming language : ActionScript 3.0
[image]

Comment: Because you declare **score** inside the loop and give it an initial value of 0. Then it goes through ++ up to 1. That's why it is always 1 on the trace.

Comment: True :)
@Organis :)
You should pot this as an answer not as a comment. I let You do that, You answered before me ;)

Comment: Could You take a look at one of my answers and tell me if i'm wrong or right?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304338/as3-event-enter-frame-error-1119/50309654#50309654
Thank You.

Comment: @tatactic No, your answer is incorrect in a several ways. First, **stage** is not a reserved word, it's a class member of the **DisplayObject** class (if that is what you wanted to say) so as long as that **GameCore** does not subclass **DisplayObject** there should not be a problem. Second, the *reserved words* link is broken. Third, is there a point at all to answer a year old post? It's probably a year since OP has resolved the issue. Also, the other answer, albeit short, pretty much hits the spot, the code seems fine. Sorry to discourage you on such an elaborate answer.

Comment: Thank You @Organis, so I will delete this answer.

Answer (score 4):

So, we have 3 kinds of syntax:

```
// 1. Variable declaration.
var a:int;

// 2. Assign value to variable.
a = 0;

// 3. Declare variable and assign value in one go.
var b:int = 1;
```

The tricky moment is that in AS3 variable declaration is **NOT** an operation. It is a construction that tells compiler you are going to use a variable with a certain name and type within a given context (*as a class member or as a timeline variable or as a local variable inside a method*). It literally does not matter where in the code you declare your variables. AS3 is, I must admit, ugly from this very perspective. The following code might look weird yet it is syntactically correct. Lets read and understand what it does and why.

```
// As long as they are declared anywhere,
// you can access these wherever you want.
i = 0;
a = 0;
b = -1;

// The 'for' loop allows a single variable declaration
// within its parentheses. It is not mandatory that
// declared variable is an actual loop iterator.
for (var a:int; i <= 10; i++)
{
    // Will trace lines of 0 0 -1 then 1 1 0 then 2 2 1 and so on.
    trace(a, i, b);

    // You can declare a variable inside the loop, why not?
    // The only thing that actually matters is that you assign
    // the 'a' value to it before you increment the 'a' variable,
    // so the 'b' variable will always be one step behind the 'a'.
    var b:int = a;

    a++;
}

// Variable declaration. You can actually put
// those even after the 'return' statement.
var i:int;
```

Let me say it again. The place where you declare your variables does not matter, just the fact you do at all. Declaring variable is not an operation. However, assigning a value is. Your code actually goes as following:

```
function bringMe(e:Event):void
{
    // Lets explicitly declare variables so that assigning
    // operations will come out into the open.
    var i:int;
    var score:int;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        // Without the confusing declaration it is
        // obvious now what's going on here.
        score = 0;
        score++;

        // Always outputs 1.
        trace(score);

        // Outputs values from 1 to 10 inclusive, as expected.
        trace(i);
    }
}
```