# In ActionScript3, a declaration of a variable is stored on heap or stack

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management, stack, heap-memory

If I have this block of code:

```
    public function test():void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var testVar:String = "";
            testVar += " a str";
        }
        trace("testvar: " + testVar);
    }
```

I still can access the testVar variable declared within the function after the for scope.

In AS3 this variable is declared on heap or stack?

What's the memory model of AS3?

Comment: Please, clarify: where exactly you access your variable? Do you meant that bottom **trace** statement? Or something else?

Comment: ok I edited I still can access the testVar variable declared within the function after the for scope.

Comment: The **for** loop is not actually a *scope*, it's just... you know... a loop block inside a scope of code (which is a **function** body in your example). You might also want to read my answer to another question, because it highlights the variable declaration details and specifics in **AS3**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555805/4687633